# Adding a "uniq" check to an existing HABTM association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a HABTM association between Student and Classroom:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :students, join_table: :classrooms_students
```

I have created an index for the join table:

```
add_index "classrooms_students", ["classroom_id", "student_id"], unique: true
```

Now I want to add a "uniq" check to this so that there are no duplicate records in the join table, and I can catch this in rails. Can I just add this check directly to the model file, or do I need a migration to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should prioritize adding that to your migration and then you could do a model level check(described below) as well.

In your case, you'd have something like:

```
class ClassroomsStudent
  validates :student_id, uniqueness: { scope: :classroom_id }
end
```

In your migration, you could then have:

```
class AddUniqueIndexClassroomsStudent
  def change
    add_index :classrooms_students, [:classroom_id, :student_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

[Add Index on ApiDoc](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_index)

[Unique Index on Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness)

Comment: I don't have a model called ClassroomsStudent. I have a model called Classroom and another called Student. There is a has_and_belongs_to_many association between the 2 (and a join table called classrooms_students)

Comment: You could add `ClassroomsStudent` model manually so that answer of  @oreoluwa could work. `class ClassroomsStudent < ActiveRecord::Base ...`

Comment: If the index has been added, then I guess you should try to link 2 similar records and see that it fails.